# Google Cloud Data Catalog - Node JS Library giving Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: Project does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-data-catalog

I am trying to use [Nodejs Library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datacatalog) for Google Cloud Data Catalog. For one project, it is working perfectly fine but for others it is giving me Project does not exist error, while I can see the project with that ID in GCP.

Example error received in application code

```
Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: Project "tech-mktg-wwc" does not exist.
```

[Project in GCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1r8L.png)

Here is a sample code that causes this error:

```
const locationPath = datacatalog.locationPath('tech-mktg-wwc','us-central1');
const req = {parent: locationPath};
const [resp] = await datacatalog.listEntryGroups(req);
```

Auth is happening via key generated for service account. I tried comparing roles/permissions for the working project with non-working one but couldn't find anything obvious. I am sure I must be missing something.

Comment: have you gone through the official setup? https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/libraries

What role does your service account have in this project?

Comment: Did you get the puzzle solved?

Comment: I had a similar error when using the Google Cloud Datastore API. For me, it seems like I had the error because I had not enabled the service in the Google Cloud Console. I went to the Datastore in the Google Cloud Console UI and there was a welcome page where I had to choose some options. After that, I retried my Node.js and it worked fine........ So maybe you need to go into DataCatalog UI for the project and check it's been enabled all ok (i.e. no initial welcome screens/setup wizards)?